# Computer Monitor Size Cons/Pros - Advice (Too Large?)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I am looking for a computer monitor and due to my poor vision, I am seeking a relatively large monitor. I've noticed that most computer monitors go up to 30", but I also see many TV-type displays (like LCD) are over 30", e.g. 42" and so on. Most of these TVs have HDMI and VGA connection types and thus should suffice my needs.

I am seeking advice as to some of the pros/cons of having that large of a monitor, e.g. reading or our the pixels too distorted at that size? I am just seeking something for text reading, i.e. programming, editors, web browsing, word processing (just text stuff). What should I be looking for ? I believe I should not care so much if it is 720p or 1080p.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30" LCD monitors are not cheap.  However, 30" LCD TVs are about 1/3 the price.  So, if a TV works for you thats probably the cheapest option.

Rather than speculate whats best for you, why not just bring a laptop with HDMI out to the store and ask to hook it up the TV?  If you explain your vision problem and the model is on display, I doubt a store would object.

Personally, I have a HTPC in my bedroom hooked up to a 36" HDTV via HDMI.  It works great for video, but its hard to read text from my bed.  I end up having to zoom the text for websites.  However, that is because Im far away.  When standing next to the TV the text is easy to read.  Also, most TVs are much brighter than monitors, you might have to adjust the brightness/contrast to look at it for long periods of time.

Comment: That's a really good tip, i.e. taking my laptop to the store and trying them first hand!  Thx!